# Junit - Comparing that two CSV streams are identical

Tags: java, csv, junit

I got two CSV streams (an Input and an Output one), which I need to compare ignoring the header and the whitespaces to check that their content is identical. 
Is there any library that allows to do that?

I am currently doing this:

```
HashSet<String>  f1 = new HashSet<String>(IOUtils.readLines(new ByteArrayInputStream(((ByteArrayOutputStream)outputStream).toByteArray())));
    HashSet<String> f2 = new HashSet<String>(IOUtils.readLines(expectedStream));
    f1.removeAll(f2); // f1 now contains only the lines which are not in f2
    Assert.assertTrue(f1.isEmpty());
```

But it is obviously not the best as it does not consider the order.

Comment: I am not exactly sure what you are asking for. Can you give a "more complete" [mcve]? I am wondering for example how outputStream and expectedStream are coming from? In that sense: what is the purpose of this test - testing some production code, or just comparing CSV file contents?

Comment: I just need to compare the content of the two Streams. Without heading and not considering the whitespace.

Comment: See my updates then.

Comment: Just added a comment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can us commons-csv or some other csv library to parse the csv and then compare the list of rows. That will allow you to compare rows column by column and will also allow you to compensate for csv escaping, different separators, etc.

If you are happy to do just string equals, you could just do what you are doing above but switch to a LinkedHashSet for the lines. This will preserve the order. I'm not sure why you are using a set at all; so maybe you should just use a list instead. Either way, you'll preserve the order.

Then you can use java 8 streams to do some processing and normalization on both collections (skip first, filter empty lines, normalize lines (trailing whitespace, newlines, etc.). Then you can collect both streams in two new lists and do a deep equals to assert that they are the same.

Comment: I've parsed the two streams in this way:

 List<CSVRecord> actualCSVRecords = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(actualCSVReader).getRecords();
  List<CSVRecord> expectedCSVRecords = CSVFormat.RFC4180.parse(expectedCSVReader).getRecords();

but if for instance  I assert that actualCSVRecords.equals(expectedCSVRecords) I got false. What is the right way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you can provide some data example of what you are comparing to what. All I know is what your test is already telling you: they are not the same. So figure out how they are different and try to compensate for that. Also, List equals may not be doing a deep equals ...

Answer (score 0):

Straight forward things that you can change:

- use `assertThat(actualSet, is(expectedSet))` - that simply compares nested structures as they should be compared
- if order is important to you, then you should not use a *HashSet* but a **LinkedHashSet** that keeps track of *insertion* order

And given your comments, your requirement ... and solution could more look like this:

```
open file 1
open file 2

read one line (as String) from each file
  throw away the very first line
  for all others: use replaceAll to simply replace spaces with nothing
  compare the two lines
```

In the end; you also "fail" when the two files have different number of lines. The only caveat here; if:

```
file1:
"value value", "B"

file2:
"value   value",    "B"
```

are **not** equal (because of spaces within the CSV "column data"), then the above wont work. Then you need a CSV parser to get your hands on the **parsed** content; to compare that.

Comment: Are you suggesting to parse the content again?

Comment: Alas; I am suggesting turn back to my very first comment. It seems that what I have tried so far isnt what you need. But then I really have **no** clue what you want. As said: put up a TRUE [mcve] and describe the input, and the expect output / behavior. As mentioned: you say you care about order, but then you simply want to use hashsets; and I have so no idea what all of that is meant to result in.

Comment: That was a solution I've found here on StackOverflow.  I got a function that takes in input a csv stream, it sorts it according to a spefied field, and returns the result in a outputStream. In this test I want to compare the outputStream content with the content of a correct sorted stream are identical. That is why I do not need to care about the header and white spaces.